# Twilio to send image using android app

Tags: android, twilio

I want users of my app to be able to send pictures and videos to each other. Can I do that using the Twilio api? I am looking for a place that not only send the pictures but also stores them so I don't have to house them in my own backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mogreet API to do that. You will have to upload your image first with media.upload  and then send it via MMS with the transaction.send. You can find the documentation at http://dev.mogreet.com